# Tensorboard: Broken pipe error and blank page

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Please could you help me run tensorboard.

Following the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux) I installed tensorflow v1.1 in a virtual linux environment using pip install.

I am trying to run the mnist example of tensorboard [mnist_with_summaries.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist)

When I run tensorboard from my local environment I receive the following error.
The summary files exist in the folder specified, and I am attempting to view tensorboard from my browser at

http://{server ip}:6006

The browser window is blank

```
[tensorflow_v1_1] % tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/logs/mnist_with_summaries
Starting TensorBoard 47 at http://0.0.0.0:6006
(Press CTRL+C to quit)
WARNING:tensorflow:Deleting accumulator 'test'
WARNING:tensorflow:Deleting accumulator 'train'
WARNING:tensorflow:path ../external/favicon.ico not found, sending 404
WARNING:tensorflow:path ../external/favicon.ico not found, sending 404
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('{my ip address here}', 36562)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 596, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 331, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 654, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 713, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 283, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 307, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You'll be hard-pressed to have someone try to comb through all of the MNIST code above to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The same happens to me. Just wait for a while (tensorboard knows how to recover) and update the webpage.

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 51670)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 596, in process_request_thread
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 331, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 654, in __init__
self.finish()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 713, in finish
self.wfile.close()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 283, in close
self.flush()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 307, in flush
self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
WARNING:tensorflow:Found more than one graph event per run, or there was a metagraph containing a graph_def, as well as one or more graph events.  Overwriting the graph with the newest event.
WARNING:tensorflow:Found more than one metagraph event per run. Overwriting the metagraph with the newest event.
```